# Add external c++ libraries to a CLion project

Tags: c++, opengl, libraries, clion

I am using CLion from Mac, and i'm having problems to understand how can i add external libraries to my project. So, how can i add external libraries to a c++ project?

Comment: While I'm not very familiar with CLion, it's simply an IDE, not a compiler. For such things you'd need a build system. I'd recommend using modern [CMake](https://cmake.org/) (version 3.2+ is reasonable, but use the latest you can).

Comment: CLion works directly with cmake-files. You have to edit CMakeLists.txt by hand

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Manually edit CMakeLists.txt adding the following lines at the end with the proper paths for your system and proper ProjectName. This config is for an Ubuntu 17.04 workstation.

```
include_directories("/usr/include/SDL2")
target_link_libraries(ProjectName "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL.so")
```

Hope this helps.

You can test it with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL Init failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "SDL Init succeeded" << endl;

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about windows?

Answer (score 7):

in `CMakeLists.txt`, add external library information.
first, you can define a logical name for the external library,
say for e.g. we want to link a shared library which has *.so* file somewhere already installed on the system,

`add_library(myLogicalExtLib SHARED IMPORTED)`

*IMPORTED* means that the library already exists and we don't need to build it here in this project.

then, we can supply the location information about this logical library as follows,

`set_target_properties(myLogicalExtLib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/my_logical_ext_lib.so")`