# Adding external libraries to CLion

Tags: clion

I am using CLion for Ubuntu. However, I am not sure how to link my external libraries or classes such as `Car.c` and `Car.h`? Can someone explain me the proper way to do so? Should the files be both in project and `cmake-build-debud` folder? Should I define the external libraries in someway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple way**
Just add the file to the main project folder
if this is your c program
/testproject/main.c
just add the header file to the same folder
/testproject/curses.h

**Advance way**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025018