# How can I use Gnuplot as a library in CLion?

Tags: c, gnuplot, clion

I'm trying to use gnuplot on my m1 Mac. I installed Gnuplot with homebrew. Now I am trying to add Gnuplot as a library to my C code but I don't now how? Another problem is that I have no idea how the library file from Gnuplot is called

I have searched for the library file but couldn't find it.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998233/add-external-c-libraries-to-a-clion-project) post could answer your question.

Comment: Yes it does. But Still don't know how the Gnuplot library file is called

Comment: gnuplot is not a library